# How can I find the segment of a line that lies within a polygon using Postgis?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, spatial-query

Given a "road", represented by a line, that crosses a "state", represented by a polygon:

What is the SQL query I can use to find the segment of the road that is within the state?

A concrete example.

I have a single line representing Route 66 which traverses the USA. I also have polygons for each state. I want to find the segment of Route 66 that lies within Texas.

Comment: read http://infogeoblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/geo-processing-in-qgis/ you want to intersect your roads with your state. This will put the attributes of the state on the segment of road.

Answer (score 2):

To create an intersection object, or for this case the segment of a line that lies within a polygon, you would use the following PostGIS query:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.ID, ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)
FROM   thePolygons a
       INNER JOIN
       theLines b
       ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) = 1
```

This would most likely be the results you are looking for.